# Using Vue 2 ; How to obtain the arrays rowKey obj with a click event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

I'm current working on a project that allows the user to upload a file and then download that file clicking on my icon. So the conundrum I'm facing is as a user I would like to click the icon to download that specific file, I'm still a fairly new Jr. Web Dev. I was wondering if someone could give me direction.

I have a `.find` for my array but for some reason its only displaying the first item within my array. Am I passing something through incorrectly?
My array (this.numberList) contains a rowKey which is the Id of that item eg. "rowkey": "2" and another "label": "filename" which contains the file name
I have my axios calls within a api folder but I believe you guys wont need it but I could be mistaken.
Thank you for reading!

**Code**

```html
<template>
  <div class="app-container">
    <el-table
      :data="list"
      style="width: 100%"
      border
      stripe
      highlight-current-row
      tooltip-effect="dark"
    >
      <el-table-column type="selection" align="center" />
      <el-table-column label="Id" width="50px">
        <template slot-scope="{ row }">
          <span class="link-type">{{ row.rowKey }}</span>
          <!--A button that is connectd the the downloadFile function-->
          <el-button
            type="text"
            size="mini"
            icon="el-icon-download"
            @click="whatFunction"
          >
          </el-button>
        </template> </el-table-column
      >>
      <el-table-column label="File Name" width="auto">
        <template slot-scope="{ row }">
          <span class="link-type">{{ row.label }}</span>
        </template>
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column label="Tools" width="auto">
        <template slot-scope="{ row }">
          <el-button type="primary" size="mini">Preview</el-button>
          <el-button type="warning" size="mini">Edit</el-button>
          <el-button type="danger" size="mini">Delete</el-button>
        </template>
      </el-table-column>
    </el-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { getMe } from '@/api/remote-search'

export default {
  name: 'FileTable',
  data() {
    return {
      list: [],
      numberList: [],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    downloadList() {
      getMe().then((response) => {
        this.list = response.data
        this.numberList = response.data
      })
    },
    theListOfIdFile() {
      return this.numberList.map((x) => x), rowKey
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.downloadList
  },
  methods: {
    whatFunction() {
      console.log(this.numberList.find((obj) => obj).rowKey)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, I do recommend that you check to install some ESlint, because you have quite some errors in your code. The `created` is wrong, you're kinda calling a `computed` but this is not how it works. And your `downloadList` computed is making an async call, this is also something that is not supposed to happen. You should move that one to a regular `method`. I recommend that you double check the Vue docs again to find out how to achieve that properly. Otherwise, you may probably need a `@click` on the `<span class="link-type">` tag or something next to it.

Comment: Give a try to `@click="findRow($event)` and in a method `findRow(e) { console.log(e) }` to find out something that could help you identify the given specific row. Like an id that you could then find out in your collection (`numberList` array I guess).

Comment: @kissu I fixed most of the eslint errors you mentioned thank you, I'm still learning vue as my strong points are react but I really do appreciate the feedback, I will refer back to the docs to fix my file. But overall I was able to discover the object I was looking for using your method. The download function is fully operational. Thank you kissu!!!!

Comment: Glad that my comment helped you solve your issue! I posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try to `@click="findRow($event)` and in a method `findRow(e) { console.log(e) }` to find out something that could help you identify the given specific row.
Like an id that you could then find out in your collection (`numberList` array I guess).